# Vertical spacing for paragraph environment

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

When I use `\paragraph{...}`, the vertical spaces in general are too big. I need to manually put `\vspace{-5em}` in front to adjust the spacing. It is not robust and unnatural. One reason may be that I have many big formulas (with many lines). Does anyone know a good way to adjust this vertical spacing automatically?

Comment: a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful.  at least the document class you are using is necessary, since that is where the initial definition of `\paragraph` is made.  and a question about your big formulas -- do you input them separately, or do you use something like the `amsmath` multi-line structures?

Comment: Thanks barbara beeton, I am using amsmath. The documentary class is book (I am writing my thesis). For the formulas, I use align, multline, etc. :-)

Answer (score 7):

`\paragraph` in `article` class is defined by

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

so the skip before is 3.25 ex by default, so adding a negative -5em spacing would almost always make it over-print the preceding text.

You can repeat the above definition use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` and reduce the spacing. (It would need to be in a local package or between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because of the `@` in the command name.)

Are you sure you need to use `\paragraph` at all? It is not a commonly used command, it is just for 4th level sections after `\section` `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`

Comment: It's probably better to mention `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: @egreg answer edited:-)

Comment: Dear David Carlisle, thank you very much for your answer. I am using (intensively) paragraph environment in my proofs to indicate different cases. Probably this is not a good habit. I am writing my thesis, so the documentary class is "book".

Comment: so in book, there is `\chapter` above `\section` so `\paragraph` (command, not an environment)  is intended to be 5th level subsections. You haven't shown how you are using it but as I said originally there is something strange if you are getting so much space that -5em space is not causing overprinting.

Answer (score 0):

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
```

Comment: `\parskip` is not directly related to the `\paragraph` command (which is a section heading) The code in this answer will affect the spacing of every paragraph in the document.